# Maven not able to find dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am trying add this dependency in my pom.xml, but maven is not able to resolve the dependency for the same.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I was working on my other computer some weeks ago. I switched my laptop, and trying to setup this project, but it's not working anymore.

Error:

```
Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.4.RELEASE
```

I see this this is available in the maven central.
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-test%7C4.3.4.RELEASE%7Cjar

Does anybody have any idea why is it happening?

Comment: Can you run `mvn` with the `-X` option and post any errors please?

Comment: What do you mean by "its not able to resolve the dependency"? Which error message do you get? Are you using an IDE, which one?

Comment: did you try adding springs repository urls to your pom? http://www.baeldung.com/spring-maven-repository

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I was expecting it will work with the mvn central.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Reek for the comment.

I added spring repository url in my pom.xml and it started working.

```
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
```

Comment: probably in your other computer, repository is defined in the main maven config file (the .m2 folder). If it's not there you would have to define it in every project's pom file. (an upvote is appreciated if it worked for you :))

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add spring specific repository to use those artifacts.

Maven works as follows:

1. Firstly Maven tries to find artifact in the local repository.
2. Otherwise Maven tries to download artifacts from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ by default.

If you wanna build your project on another computer for the first time than there is no local repository at the moment. There are two possible reasons for Error on the second stage:

1. Maven central repository is unavailable from another computer: check [this URL](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-test/4.3.4.RELEASE/).
2. Mirror of Maven central is misconfigured in settings.xml like this:

```xml
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>central-proxy</id>
    <name>Proxy of Maven Central</name>
    <url>http://some/invalid/url/here</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Detailed logs are required.